# Date назад на 10 лет

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите написать функцию которая с нынешнего времени пойдет назад на 10 лет и возвратит дату время год неделю и все о дате на английском

Answer (score 2):

В JS это всё можно просто сделать с помощью объекта [Date](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Простой пример:

```
var now = new Date();
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() - 10);
```

И потом обращаетесь к методам даты и берете данные что вам надо, список методов доступны по ссылке выше, вот некоторые из них:

```
getDate()   Returns the day of the month (from 1-31)
getDay()    Returns the day of the week (from 0-6)
getFullYear()   Returns the year (four digits)
getHours()  Returns the hour (from 0-23)
getMilliseconds()   Returns the milliseconds (from 0-999)
getMinutes()    Returns the minutes (from 0-59)
getMonth()  Returns the month (from 0-11)
getSeconds()    Returns the seconds (from 0-59)
```

Только учитывайте что некоторые методы возвращают данные отсчитывая от 0, а не 1, тот же метод `getHours` или `getMonth`, так что чтоб вывести правильное число добавьте ещё 1.

Answer (score 2):

Для манипуляций с годом:

- [`Date.prototype.getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)
- [`Date.prototype.setYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setYear)

Для вывода локализованных данных ("на английском"):

- [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Другой способ форматировать даты, более производительный в случае необходимости работы со множеством дат - заранее компилировать формат с помощью:

- [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

```js
var locale = 'en-US';
var d = new Date;
d.setYear(d.getFullYear() - 10);


console.log(d.toLocaleDateString(locale));
console.log(d.toLocaleTimeString(locale));
console.log(d.toLocaleString(locale, {weekday: 'long'}))

var options = { 
  weekday: 'long', 
  year: 'numeric', 
  month: 'long', 
  day: 'numeric' 
 };
var dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, options);
console.log(dateTimeFormat.format(d));
```

---

Comment: Внимание, обнаружен самый простой способ вернуть 2007-й.